# Pine script v5 - Alert not sync with List of trade by time frame - how to fix

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am newbie in this case,
I use code from other and edit it
When i setting alert  in time frame 4h, the result is no sync with the list of trade , it may be same 5m time frame.
i found it may be the Resolution input . i want alert same with the list of trade by time frame.
how to do it?
i set alert for BTC 4h, but alert can not show when list of trades and chart show the order
[Look at Alert log, it not show same list of trade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVK9C.jpg)
here is the code

```
//@version=5
// Original Author: @JayRogers
//Open Close Cross Strategy R5.1 revised by JustUncleL
//edit

strategy(title = "Open Close Cross Strategy R5.1 v5script", shorttitle = "OCC Strategy R5.1  v5script", overlay=true,initial_capital=100,default_qty_value=10,default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,commission_value=0.1,margin_long = 1./20*10, margin_short = 1./20*10,calc_on_order_fills=true,pyramiding=1)

// *** USE AT YOUR OWN RISK ***
// Change log my ver - ver1 - 
//1- Convert to V5 pine script
//2- Add Alert message  
//3- My default setting is best TP for 4h timeframe - BTC - backtest 1900 bar from Nov - 28 - 2022
// === INPUTS ===
useRes      = input(defval = true, title = "Use Alternate Resolution?")
intRes      = input(defval = 6,    title = "Multiplier for Alernate Resolution")
stratRes    = timeframe.ismonthly? str.tostring(str.tonumber(timeframe.period)*intRes,"###M") : timeframe.isweekly? str.tostring(str.tonumber(timeframe.period)*intRes,"###W") : timeframe.isdaily?  str.tostring(str.tonumber(timeframe.period)*intRes,"###D") : timeframe.isintraday ? str.tostring(str.tonumber(timeframe.period)*intRes,"####") : '60'
basisType   = input.string(defval = "TEMA", title = "MA Type: ", options = ["SMA", "EMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "HullMA", "LSMA", "ALMA", "SSMA", "TMA"])
basisLen    = input(defval = 4, title = "MA Period")
offsetSigma = input(defval = 6, title = "Offset for LSMA / Sigma for ALMA")
offsetALMA  = input(defval = 0.85, title = "Offset for ALMA")
scolor      = input(false, title="Show coloured Bars to indicate Trend?")
delayOffset = input(defval = 0, title = "Delay Open/Close MA (Forces Non-Repainting)")
tradeType   = input.string("BOTH", title="What trades should be taken : ", options=["LONG", "SHORT", "BOTH", "NONE"])

// === /INPUTS ===

// Constants colours that include fully non-transparent option.
green100 = #008000FF
lime100  = #00FF00FF
red100   = #FF0000FF
blue100  = #0000FFFF
aqua100  = #00FFFFFF
darkred100 = #8B0000FF
gray100 = #808080FF

// === BASE FUNCTIONS ===
// Returns MA input selection variant, default to SMA if blank or typo.
variant(type, src, len, offSig, offALMA) =>
    v1 = ta.sma(src, len)                                                  // Simple
    v2 = ta.ema(src, len)                                                  // Exponential
    v3 = 2 * v2 - ta.ema(v2, len)                                          // Double Exponential
    v4 = 3 * (v2 - ta.ema(v2, len)) + ta.ema(ta.ema(v2, len), len)               // Triple Exponential
    v5 = ta.wma(src, len)                                                  // Weighted
    v6 = ta.vwma(src, len)                                                 // Volume Weighted
    v7 = 0.0
    v7 := na(v7[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len) : (v7[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
    v8 = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src, len / 2) - ta.wma(src, len), math.round(math.sqrt(len)))   // Hull
    v9 = ta.linreg(src, len, offSig)                                       // Least Squares
    v10 = ta.alma(src, len, offALMA, offSig)                               // Arnaud Legoux
    v11 = ta.sma(v1,len)                                                   // Triangular (extreme smooth)
    // SuperSmoother filter
    // © 2013  John F. Ehlers
    a1 = math.exp(-1.414*3.14159 / len)
    b1 = 2*a1*math.cos(1.414*3.14159 / len)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = (-a1)*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
    v12 = 0.0
    v12 := c1*(src + nz(src[1])) / 2 + c2*nz(v12[1]) + c3*nz(v12[2])
    type=="EMA"?v2 : type=="DEMA"?v3 : type=="TEMA"?v4 : type=="WMA"?v5 : type=="VWMA"?v6 : type=="SMMA"?v7 : type=="HullMA"?v8 : type=="LSMA"?v9 : type=="ALMA"?v10 : type=="TMA"?v11: type=="SSMA"?v12: v1

// security wrapper for repeat calls
reso(exp, use, res) => use ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, exp, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : exp

// === /BASE FUNCTIONS ===

// === SERIES SETUP ===
closeSeries     = variant(basisType, close[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)
openSeries      = variant(basisType, open[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)

// GetWinRate() returns the strategy's win rate (percentage
// of profitable trades). Set 'includeEvens' to 'true' to
// treat break-even trades as profitable setups too.
GetWinRate(includeEvens = false) =>
    winTradeCount = strategy.wintrades + 
         (includeEvens ? strategy.eventrades : 0)
    (winTradeCount / strategy.closedtrades) * 100
barTimeFormatted = str.format_time(time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', "UTC+7")
// === /SERIES ===

// === /COMMENT ===
//Set find Price numbar SL Long / Short
InlowestClose = input(20,"Enter number bar Stop Loss Long",group = "Find Price numbar Long / Short Setting for Alert")
InhightClose = input(20,"Enter number bar Stop Loss Short",group = "Find Price numbar Long / Short Setting for Alert")
lowestClose = ta.lowest(low, InlowestClose)
hightClose = ta.highest(high, InhightClose)
//TP/SL target Long / Short
LTP1 = input(1.01,"TP1 Long - 1.01 is 1% from Enrty",group = "Take Profit Long / Short from Entry for Alert")
LTP2 = input(1.03,"TP2 Long - 1.03 is 3% from Entry",group = "Take Profit Long / Short from Entry for Alert")

STP1 = input(1.01,"TP1 Short - 1.01 is 1% from Enrty",group = "Take Profit Long / Short from Entry for Alert")
STP2 = input(1.03,"TP2 Short - 1.03 is 3% from Entry",group = "Take Profit Long / Short from Entry for Alert")

Longtakeprofit1 = open * LTP1
Longtakeprofit2 = open * LTP2
Shorttakeprofit1 = open-((open * STP1)-open)
Shorttakeprofit2 = open-((open * STP2)-open)

// Comment Long/ short
//CoEntryLo = "buy - Entry: " + str.tostring(close)+ "\n" + "TP1: " + str.tostring(Longtakeprofit1,"#.##") + " SL: " + str.tostring(lowestClose,"#.##") +" Winrate " + str.tostring(GetWinRate(),"00.0")+"%"+  " Time " + str.tostring(barTimeFormatted)
//CoEntrySh = "sell - Entry: " + str.tostring(close)+ "\n" + "TP1: " + str.tostring(Shorttakeprofit1,"#.##")+ " SL: " + str.tostring(hightClose,"#.##") +" Winrate " + str.tostring(GetWinRate(),"00.0")+"%"+  " Time " + str.tostring(barTimeFormatted)


// === PLOTTING ===

// Get Alternate resolution Series if selected.
closeSeriesAlt = reso(closeSeries, useRes, stratRes)
openSeriesAlt = reso(openSeries, useRes, stratRes)
//
trendColour = (closeSeriesAlt > openSeriesAlt) ? color.rgb(0,255,85,80) : color.rgb(229,10,10, 75)
bcolour     = (closeSeries > openSeriesAlt) ? lime100 : red100
barcolor(scolor?bcolour:na, title = "Bar Colours")
closeP=plot(closeSeriesAlt, title = "Close Series", color = trendColour, linewidth=2, style = plot.style_line)
openP=plot(openSeriesAlt, title = "Open Series", color = trendColour, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line)
fill(closeP,openP,color=trendColour,transp=80)

// === /PLOTTING ===

// === ALERT conditions
xlong       = ta.crossover(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
xshort      = ta.crossunder(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
longCond    = xlong   // alternative: longCond[1]? false : (xlong or xlong[1]) and close>closeSeriesAlt and close>=open
shortCond   = xshort  // alternative: shortCond[1]? false : (xshort or xshort[1]) and close<closeSeriesAlt and close<=open
// === /ALERT conditions.
// === /ALERT message ===
Lalert_msg = "Long "+" Winrate " + str.tostring(GetWinRate(),"00.00")+ "%" + " Current Price "+ str.tostring(close)+ "\n" + "Bars from prev signal:" + str.tostring(ta.barssince(xlong[1]))     + "\n"  + " Take Profit 1:"   + str.tostring(Longtakeprofit1,"#.##")   + "\n"+  " Take Profit 2:"  + str.tostring(Longtakeprofit2,"#.##")   + "\n"   +  " Stop Loss:"     + str.tostring(lowestClose)  + "\n"   +  " Time " + str.tostring(barTimeFormatted)  
Salert_msg = "Short " + " Winrate " + str.tostring(GetWinRate(),"00.00")+ "%" + " Current Price "+ str.tostring(close)  + "\n"   + "Bars from prev signal:" + str.tostring(ta.barssince(xshort[1])) + "\n"  + " Take Profit 1:"   + str.tostring(Shorttakeprofit1,"#.##")  + "\n"   +  " Take Profit 2:"   + str.tostring(Shorttakeprofit2,"#.##") + "\n"   +    "Stop Loss:"  + str.tostring(hightClose) + "\n"    +  " Time " + str.tostring(barTimeFormatted)

// === STRATEGY ===
// stop loss
slPoints    = input.int(0, "Initial Stop Loss Points (zero to disable)", minval = 0 , step = 1,group = "Stop Loss Calulate Strategy")
tpPoints    = input.int(0, "Initial Target Profit Points (zero for disable)", minval = 0,step = 1,group = "Stop Loss Calulate Strategy")
// Include bar limiting algorithm
ebar            = input.int(defval = 1900, title="Number of Bars for Back Testing", minval=0, step = 1,group = "Bars Backtest")
dummy           = input(false,        title="- SET to ZERO for Daily or Longer Timeframes",group = "Bars Backtest" )
//
// Calculate how many mars since last bar
tdays       = (timenow-time)/60000.0  // number of minutes since last bar
tperiod =timeframe.period
tdays       := timeframe.ismonthly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/4.3/str.tonumber(tperiod) : timeframe.isweekly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/str.tonumber(tperiod) : timeframe.isdaily? tdays/1440.0/str.tonumber(tperiod) : tdays/str.tonumber(tperiod) // number of bars since last bar
//
//set up exit parameters
TP = tpPoints>0?tpPoints:na
SL = slPoints>0?slPoints:na

// Make sure we are within the bar range, Set up entries and exit conditions
if ((ebar==0 or tdays<=ebar) and tradeType!="NONE")
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=longCond==true and tradeType!="SHORT", alert_message = Lalert_msg)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when=shortCond==true and tradeType!="LONG", alert_message = Salert_msg)
    strategy.close("long", when = shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG")
    strategy.close("short", when = longCond==true and tradeType=="SHORT")
    strategy.exit("XL", from_entry = "long", profit = TP, loss = SL,comment_profit = "ELong TP ✅",comment_loss = "ELong SL ❌")
    strategy.exit("XS", from_entry = "short", profit = TP, loss = SL,comment_profit = "EShort TP ✅",comment_loss = "EShort SL ❌")

// === /STRATEGY ===
// eof
```

the alert will show same list of trades by time frame

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I upload a image, you can focus on alert log, i set alert for BTC 4h, but alert can not show when list of trades and chart show the order [img]https://i.ibb.co/zSS20v4/Alert.jpg[/img]